# JQuery 3.4.1 Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, upgrade

After upgrade jQuery 3.4.0 to 3.4.1, on `blur()` or `focus()` events on input I'm getting `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` error.

```
that.container.on('click', '.binary_field', function(){
    $("input:focus").blur();
}
```

I think that may be cause of this change in jquery source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/24d71ac70406f522fc1b09bf7c4025251ec3aee6?diff=unified#diff-031bb62d959e7e4949d1847c82507f33L579-R583

Comment: Can you please add the full code which creates the issue in to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in jQuery 3.4.1:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4417

Use the JavaScript .blur() instead of the jQuery method.

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems good, there is a workaround in your case, remove jquery for this line.

You can replace

```
$("input:focus").blur()
```

by

```
document.activeElement && document.activeElement.blur() 
// Test if there is a focused element, if yes remove the focus
```

or (with jQuery and VanillaJs)

```
$(document.activeElement)[0].blur()
// or
$("input:focus")[0].blur()
```

It's the same behavior

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but in my app I'm using blur and focus element to launch other behaviours as well